# Find duplicates rows from specific columns

Tags: powerbi, duplicates

i’m new to power bi and my management asked me to make an automated dashboard,

one of the difficulties that i’m facing right now:

I have table going over 5 years of results to certain employees,

I need to see if there’s an employee failed in the same year and i want to see how many times he failed,

So i need to count the row the employee has failed the test in same year more than ones.

I tried sooooo many formulas with no luck at all,i even tried to use R and python langauges
please i need you help and support.

This a sample ( fahad failed twice in one year)
( Mohammed only once)
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr3np.jpg)

and this how i want to present it

[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV7BB.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample data and how you want to visualize them.

Comment: I hope it’s clear now 

Comment: Is your date column formatted as a date and are they looking at the same display?  it looks like you may have mm/dd/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: yes you’re right but it’s only a sample not the real data because i can’t share it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic approach to how you could potentially handle your requirement.

1. Make sure your date column in the table you're using or date table is formatted as a date
2. Create a new calculated column that extracts the year from the date.

   ```
   Year = YEAR(Table[Date])
   ```
3. Create another calculated column that concatenates the employee name and the year.

   ```
   Employee_Year = Table[Employee] & " " & Table[Year]
   ```
4. Create a measure that counts the number of times and employee failed the the test in the same year.

   ```
       Count of Failures = 
   CALCULATE(
       COUNT(Table[Employee_Year]),
       FILTER(
           Table,
           Table[Result] = "Failed"
               && Table[Employee_Year] = MAX(Table[Employee_Year])
       )
   )
   ```

Change out the generic references I used with your table and values.